# Método .clone() do jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou precisando de cada vez que clicar na div `Mais`, clonar o conteúdo total dela e colocar logo abaixo. Porem não está dando certo, poderiam me dizer em que estou errando ?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#maisfoto').on('click', function () {
    $( ".fileinput fileinput-new" ).clone().appendTo( ".fileinput fileinput-new" );
  });
});
```

```css
div#maisfoto {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  float: right;
  width: 43px;
  height: 21px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: brown;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="maisfoto">Mais</div>
<div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
<div id="tamb" class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists thumbnail" style="padding-bottom: 15px;">Tamanho esperado: 586px x 184px</div>
    <div>
        <span class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Selecionar Imagens</span><span class="fileinput-exists">Trocar</span><input type="file" name="..."></span>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remover</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit 2:A pedido do preview da imagem**

tudo funcionando com plugin, botao, add, remove e preview segue codigo, ta dando uns erros no console, isso ai você da uma olhada e corrige ;)

```html
 <html>
  <style>
   div#maisfoto {
   text-align: center;
   color: white;
   float: right;
   width: 43px;
   height: 21px;
   border-radius: 20px;
   background-color: brown;
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: table;
   padding-bottom: 3px;
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">    
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/css/jasny-bootstrap.css"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/css/jasny-bootstrap.css.map"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/css/jasny-bootstrap.min.css"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <body>
   <div id="maisfoto">Mais</div>  
   
   <div class="fileinput fileinput-new aquiClonar" data-provides="fileinput">
    <div class="fileinput-preview thumbnail" data-trigger="fileinput" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"></div>
    <div>
     <span class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Select image</span><span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span><input type="file" name="..."></span>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </body>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#maisfoto').on('click', function () {
     $( ".aquiClonar:first" ).clone().appendTo( "body" );              
     
     $('.aquiClonar a').click(function(){
      console.log('remover()');
       $(this).parents('.aquiClonar').remove();
     });
    });
    
     });                  
  </script>
 </html>
```

Comentários do código

```
    $(document).ready(function () { // quando terminar de carregar a pagina
            $('#maisfoto').on('click', function () { // ao clicar na div id maisfoto
                $( ".aquiClonar:first" ).clone().appendTo( "body" ); // procura a class aquiClonar e pega o primeiro (first) e add na tag body

                $('.aquiClonar a').click(function(){ // ao clicar em uma tag a que contenha class aquiClonar faz o evento click
                    console.log('remover()'); // log para debug
                     $(this).parents('.aquiClonar').remove(); // this se referencia ao selector a que por sua vez chama a classe superior aquiClonar e seleciona, após isso ele remove a tag e tudo que conter nela
                });
            });

          });
```

**Edit 3: A pedido do não remover o primeiro elemento:**

```
    $(document).ready(function () { // quando terminar de carregar a pagina
            $('#maisfoto').on('click', function () { // ao clicar na div id maisfoto
                var clone = $('.aquiClonar:first').clone(); // clonar
                clone.append("<a href='#' class='btn btn-default fileinput-exists' data-dismiss='fileinput'>Remove</a>"); // Adicionar o remove somente nos clones
                $( "body" ).append(clone); // procura a class aquiClonar e pega o primeiro (first) e add na tag body

                $('.aquiClonar a').click(function(){ // ao clicar em uma tag a que contenha class aquiClonar faz o evento click
                    console.log('remover()'); // log para debug
                     $(this).parents('.aquiClonar').remove(); // this se referencia ao selector a que por sua vez chama a classe superior aquiClonar e seleciona, após isso ele remove a tag e tudo que conter nela
                });
            });

          });
```

Comment: Deu certo mais preciso que quando abra o preview venha apenas o preview do filho que eu quero, pode me ajudar fazer isto ? Estou utilizando o http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput para montar o preview

Comment: Outra coisa quando clono pela segunda vez, ele criar o dobro, por causa da class, então toda classe com mesmo nome ele clona.

Comment: @Segio vou comentar nos fontes um momento...

Comment: tem como bloquear para não poder excluir o ultimo, porque se caso a pessoa for remover e remover todos e caso o ultimo esteja juntos deste, o "mais" não funciona mais.

Comment: @RenanRodrigues feito mais um edit ai na resposta para resolver o problema do primeiro elemento não remover

Comment: vlw cara. ajudou muito

Comment: Esqueci de avisar que o primeiro elemento ficará sem a tag remover... mas já conseguiu pelo jeito né

Comment: Sim. deu certinho